# SignalR cross domain and IIS 7.5 path to hub only works locally on the server, how to access it externally?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, signalr

I am self hosting a SignalR Hubs server within my C# WinForms application:

```
        string url = "http://localhost:8081/";

        m_signalrServer = new Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hosting.Self.Server(url);

        // Map the default hub url (/signalr)
        m_signalrServer.MapHubs();

        // Start the SignalRserver
        m_signalrServer.Start();
```

My ASP.NET web application is acting as the SignalR Hubs JavaScript client:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.0.0-alpha2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8081/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost:8081/signalr'

        var myHub = $.connection.myHub;

        $.connection.hub.error(function () {
            console.log("Error!");
        });

        $.connection.hub.start()
        .done(function () {
            console.log("Connected!");
        })
        .fail(function () { console.log("Could not connect!"); });           
    });   
</script>
```

This code works properly when I am using the Server's web browser as it can access `http://localhost:8081/signalr/hubs`.

However, when you browse the site externally via `http://serverip`, the SignalR fails because the JQuery script is looking for a `http://localhost:8081/signalr` (which I believe it looks for on your local computer).

I have changed:

```
$.connection.hub.url = 'http://serverip:8081/signalr'
```

and I enabled browsing of the website on 8081 and can browse to the website via `http://serverip:8081`. However, browsing to `http://serverip:8081/SignalR/Hubs` can not find the hub file that is available from `http://localhost:8081/siganlr/hubs`.

Also, as a test I enabled SignalR within the ASP.NET web application via the App_Start folder -> RegisterHubs.cs file : `RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();`

Doing this allows me to browse to `http://serverip:8081/signalr/hubs` or `http://serverip/signalr/hubs` and I can see the hubs being generated by the ASP.NET website. This is not what I want because this is not the hubs I am hosting from my C# WinForms application.

Once again, browsing to `http://serverip:8081/signalr/hubs` does not find signalr or the hubs file that exists on `http://localhost:8081/signalr/hubs`. Does anyone know how I can make this file available to my ASP.NET web application so that I can make SignalR work externally?

EDIT: I forgot to mention 8081 is open on the server firewall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to:

```
string url = "http://*:8081/";

m_signalrServer = new Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hosting.Self.Server(url);
```

Comment: Thank-you. This has fixed my issue. After lots of searching, yesterday I also found this post which has to do with your answer as well as the issue I was having: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/684 (in case anyone else runs into this).