# Is it possible to load javascript file with http://localhost as the source?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Is it possible to load a JavaScript file with `http://localhost` as the source?

ex:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8081/signalr/hubs" language="javascript"></script>`

I am using a script like this in my asp.net web application. It is working properly when running locally on my computer.

Once I put the web application onto a live server and I access the page that has the above script, the GET for that script returns status "aborted". Is it possible to use this reference when accessing the website externally?

Note*: `http://localhost:8081/signalr/hubs` has a javascript script called Hubs.js. Navigating to it from a browser on the server displays the script.

Comment: Use relative paths from your current project, if it's a local server load it like `signalr/hubs/...`. Those paths will work when moved to a new server.

Comment: depends on browser type and its security options. And dont't forget - others have other data on theirs localhosts

Comment: @elclanrs the problem i have is that the script that resides at http://localhost:8081/signalr/hubs is generated by another application on the server that is hosting a service on :8081

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`localhost` means the current computer.
It only means your server if the browser is on the same computer as the server.

Comment: Is there anyways to resolve the reference to http://localhost:8081/signalr/hubs so that I can use this script? Also, why does the script load up even when the GET status is "Aborted". Viewing page source I can see the script.

Comment: @Mausimo: You need to use a publicly-visible domain name and port (eg, `example.com`).

Comment: That means it could execute the script.  That has nothing to do with the presence of the `<script>` tag in the DOM.

Comment: can i use an IP or does it have to be a domain name? ie.) http://myip:8081/signalr/hubs

Comment: @Mausimo: As long as the client can connect to it, it doesn't matter.  You can use the same hostname as your site itself.

Comment: I have opened the 8081 port on the firewall on the server. If I use a web browser and try to browse to serverip:8081/signalr/hubs I get "HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid". Where as if i browse on the server on localhost:8081/signalr/hubs I get the javascript. Using http://serverip:8081/signalr/hubs as the script source also returns 400 Bad Request. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I actually ended up solving my issue in another thread specific to signalr. I was trying to make sense of what was happening. In case anyone is having the same issue, here is the post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13518973/signalr-cross-domain-and-iis-7-5-path-to-hub-only-works-locally-on-the-server-h